# Accessing "value" Property of td element using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following TD element:

```
 <td>
<input type="radio" name="n1" onclick="f1(this)" value="Moon">
</td>
```

How do i access it by its "value" property using Jquery

Comment: By value do you mean the value of the input element inside the td ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var obj=$("td input:radio[value=Moon]");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$elem = $("input[value='moon']");
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer please.